# Variables which names only contain digits (kotlin/android)

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to create variables that should be named exactly like its API response to save data inside them. So that's why I have to create variables like this:

```
val 50: String
val 100: String
```

But as you know I can't do this so how can I create variables which names only contain digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Gson` library to convert Json api to kotlin Data class, add the same `@SerializedName("key_api")` annotation.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class YourResponse {
    @SerializedName("50")
    val firstVariableName: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("100")
    val secondVariableName: String? = null
}
```

With this annotation, `Gson` will map the key of that Json with your variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You do it by wrapping with `

```
// define
val `50`: String 
val `100`: String
// access
`50` = "123"
`100` = "456"
println("${`50`}${`100`}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Retrofit` with `Gson`, you should use `@SerializedName` [Check this out](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support)